# Use of WorkManagr API in J2EE application is viable?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

J2EE specification says its not advisable to create or spawn user defined threads into application logic. The reason as i understood is to avoid resource contention, synchronization issues and memory leaks.

But it also suggest to use ManagedExecutorService or WorkManager API implementation. Both of these implementations also spawns threads under the hood.

Then how it is appropriate to use these API's and not using Threads directly ?

Comment: Is that a current J2EE specification ?  https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=237

Comment: @AlexCornford if you read the very start of the JSR 237 home page, you will see that it was withdrawn and merged with JSR 236.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the WorkManager API is only available to [JCA resource adapters](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=16). Thus I'll mostly address the ManagedExecutorService, but most of what I say is applicable to WorkManager as well.

The difference between using ManagedExecutorService / WorkManager and creating your own threads is that the application server *manages* the underlying threads. This means the threads you use with this API, and more generally via the `javax.enterprise.concurrent.*` classes, whether implicitly in the case of asynchronous task submission with a [ManagedExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html), or explicitly vith a  [ManagedThreadFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedThreadFactory.html), will have a guaranteed consistency with the services provided by the application server, in particular transactions management, security, resources management etc.

Comment: can you please tell me how can i use ManagedExecutorService/ExecutorService in my application deployed on Jboss4. I mean how to register them with container ?